# Define which models will be converted to activerecord timezone config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I'm looking for a way to use the ActiveRecord timezone configuration only in some models,
or a way to disable it in some methods that I don't need.

Something like this:

Models User, Access, Sale use the same timezone as application.rb:
config.time_zone = "xxxx"

but Models Lap, CheckIn don't use timezone setting or UTC for those.

I thought about using a after_initialize method which clear the time_zone config
and something like a *after_free* (I know that it dont exists) to back the timezone setting from the old configured value.

Isn't it a simple way to do this??

Comment: i guess i would build myself a 'with_timezone' method in wich i set the timezone for an executed block https://gist.github.com/458992

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to do this on a particular model, or for particular fields on a particular model, the method described in [this post](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2008/11/01/turn-off-rors-automatic-timezone-conversion-for-columns/) worked well for me.

```
# Turn it off for just some columns
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes
   [:created_at, :published_at]
 end
end

# Turn it off for the whole model
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.time_zone_aware_attributes
    false
  end
end
```

And in case it helps, here's my test case:

```
before :all do
  @current_tz = Time.zone
  # Test usually runs in UTC; test this as if in production, per config/application.rb
  Time.zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
end

after :all do
  Time.zone = @current_tz
end

it 'should report UTC time as UTC time' do
  new_obj = MyModel.create(start_time: DateTime.new(2013, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0))
  new_obj.reload
  new_obj.start_time.to_s.should == 'Sun, 31 Mar 2013 00:00:00 +0000'
end
```

Comment: It seems that you need to call `Model.reset_column_information` if you decide to change `skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes` or `time_zone_aware_attributes` after you've already queried via that model. Also, the former can be modified per model via array mutator methods, but the latter must be redefined on the subclass (as you did) since it's linked with `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: Also, I noticed that though this works, the "unconverted" times are `Time` objects rather than `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. Not sure what the impacts are, though.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this you are looking for?](http://tamersalama.com/2011/01/10/rails-disable-timezone-conversions/)

Hope it helps.

EDIT: try to perform something like this:
On your

```
class Lap < ActionController::Base
 before_filter :remove_time_zone

 def remove_time_zone
  ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
 end
end
```

OR:

```
Lap.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
```

Comment: no, this is the commom behaviour editing config/environment.rb works for all your app. I wish to select determine which models should be configurated with these settings and which will not. eg. If I've got a model that I would like to have different timezones for different models.

Comment: But you did you try it on your model setting?

Comment: wow! this edit really changed the last answer. I think this will solve it.

Comment: I'm testing it applying on model instead of controller. I'm setting the callbacks to set this property to false. But it would inflict in changes on all models right? I need to set it to false on before_* and back to true on after_* ... is that right?